# Pygame OpenGL init causes an X Error

Tags: opengl, pygame

`-> pygame.display.set_mode(display, HWSURFACE|OPENGL|DOUBLEBUF)
(Pdb) s
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  28
  Current serial number in output stream:  29`

I've seen one other answer to this question related to video drivers, but I feel like I've already run my game at least once with the same video drivers installed. I'd just like to know if there's another possible cause for this issue before I reinstall my drivers for the umpteenth time on Linux.

Comment: Could you link the other answer too? We might be able to see something you don't from the other scenario; From what I can assume, GLX (which is basically what connects OGL with the X window system on linux) is not able to create a GL context; I can't really tell, since I have never used pygame, but if you are not creating a gl context using glx directly, your drivers might very well be outdated/broken in some way.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/893922/ubuntu-16-04-gives-x-error-of-failed-request-badvalue-integer-parameter-out-o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I'm an idiot. I ran updates on Linux last night and I never restarted after updating since I don't have an automatic reboot set up on my computer yet. It's fixed, now, anyway.